# Allow users to migrate their own question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Currently it is often clear to a user that a question really belongs on another site. This is especially true after a comment to that effect is received on the question by another user. Migration by the user however means:

1. registering on the other site
2. going back to the original site, editing the question, copying the content
3. creating another question on the other site
4. pasting in the content (which is hopefully still in the clipboard)
5. going back to the other site, cancelling the edit and then deleting the question, hoping that no answer has been given.

This is not very obvious, user friendly or efficient. Besides that, in my experience, people don't like to be asked to delete their questions if you hint to them what they should do.

So I would propose that we let users migrate their own unanswered questions instead. Possibly this requires some safeguard, e.g. a trusted user notifying them about the other site. If the user does not exist on the other site the user could be automatically asked to register for the other site as well so that the other site does not have to deal with unregistered users all the time.

Comment: You can always delete first and as long as you have the URL you'll always be able to view the question.

Comment: Yeah, and users know this, right?

Comment: Given how many times I've seen "0 down vote favorite" at the top of posts, I'd have to say they probably figure it out relatively easily. Or, y'know, copy the text before deleting.

Comment: @Shog9 *Never* seen it happen in practice. If they copy, they forget to remove the original. Most of the time the question will stay, get downvoted or answered and never migrated.

Comment: Note to readers: I think the solution is to allow off topic -> should be posted to other site as close reason and then let the user migrate the question if the site is not in the short list for migration, but only if the question is put on hold for this reason. This however requires a rethink of the way close reasons are handled.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Currently it is often clear to a user that a question really belongs on another site

No no no!

People suggest "migrate to X" all the time without knowing the scope of X. Several sites have chatbots setup already to prevent these sorts of migrations, by posting messages to chat when users suggest their site as a migration or "belongs on X" site.

Sites with common migrations already have paths. Moderators can also migrate questions which actually fit, or discuss with target site mods. This is far preferable from my perspective.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes the worse UX is when someone says that, they repost or it gets migrated, and since it's not appropriate for the target site they get downvoted _there_ too...

Comment: Hmmm, yeah, but I've also seen that happen after their question gets closed for being off topic. I don't know what's worse in that case. If it gets migrated you would at least not get downvotes / close votes on the original site.